# Why I can't receive data by a socket

Tags: java, python, sockets

I can send data in python and received in server, but after sleep more than 1ms(if do some For-loops(E.g：  for i in range(0, 60):
        print i), the result is same), I use socket to send data, but can't be received in java server.

There are code:
A client is writen in python2:

```
address = ('127.0.0.1', 9898)
ccc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
ccc.connect(address)
ccc.send("client" + str(1) + ":before time.sleep send1111\n")
time.sleep(0.001)
ccc.send("client2:222222 after time.sleep\n")# if sleep 0.0009,can received,but 0.001 can't
```

A server is written in java:

```
 ReceiveListener listener = new ReceiveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReceived(int clientId, String msg) {
                System.out.println(clientId + ":" + msg);
            }
        };
        ClientManager clientManager = ClientManager.getInstance(listener, 9898);
        clientManager.start();
```

And this is class manage the client:

```
public class ClientManager {
    private static ServerThread serverThread = null;
    private static ClientManager instance = null;
    private final int port;
    private ReceiveListener receiveListener = null;

    private ClientManager(ReceiveListener receiveListener, int port) {
        this.receiveListener = receiveListener;
        this.port = port;
        serverThread = new ServerThread(receiveListener, port);
    }

    public static ClientManager getInstance(ReceiveListener receiveListener, int port) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (ClientManager.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ClientManager(receiveListener, port);
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void stop() {
        serverThread.Stop();
        serverThread = null;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (serverThread == null) {
            serverThread = new ServerThread(receiveListener, port);
        }
        new Thread(serverThread).start();
    }

    public static class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        private ReceiveListener receiveListener;
        private static Map<Integer, HandleMsgTask> tasks = new HashMap<>();
        private final AtomicBoolean isExit = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        private ServerSocket server;
        int i = 0;

        public ServerThread(ReceiveListener receiveListener, int port) {
            try {
                this.receiveListener = receiveListener;
                this.server = new ServerSocket(port);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("failed：" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isExit.get()) {
                    System.out.println("wait devices... ... " + i);
                    Socket client = server.accept();
                    HandleMsgTask task = new HandleMsgTask(i, client, receiveListener);
                    new Thread(task).start();
                    tasks.put(i, task);
                    i++;
                    System.out.println("No:" + i);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static class HandleMsgTask implements Runnable {
            public final int clientId;
            public final Socket client;
            public static boolean connectStop = false;
            private final ReceiveListener ReceiveListener;

            public HandleMsgTask(int i, Socket client, ReceiveListener ReceiveListener) {
                this.clientId = i;
                this.client = client;
                this.ReceiveListener = ReceiveListener;
            }

            public void disconnectClient() {
                connectStop = true;
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final String address = client.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
                    System.out.println(clientId + ":" + address);
                    InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    while (reader.ready() && !connectStop) {
                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        if (ReceiveListener != null) {
                            ReceiveListener.onReceived(clientId, line);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop() {
            if (tasks != null) {
                for (HandleMsgTask task : tasks.values()) {
                    task.disconnectClient();
                }
                tasks.clear();
            }
            isExit.set(true);
            if (server != null) {
                try {
                    server.close();
                    System.out.println("close server");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Because you are misusing `ready()`. You don't have anything else to do in this read loop, so it is pointless even testing it, and you are actually exiting the loop when it is false, which means that unless data is already available to be read the moment you enter it you will miss it. Just remove this pointless test and let your loop block in `readLine()`. And exit the loop if you get `null`: otherwise you are ignoring end of stream and pointlessly continuing with the read loop. And don't put sleeps into networking code.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

As user207421 said,I misused ready(); I Change the code bellow and solve the problem:
edit:

```
 while (!bIsStopped.get() && ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
                    if (newMsgRecListener != null) {
                        newMsgRecListener.onMsgRec(clientId, line);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should test `bIsStopped` first, not after you have probably blocked and read a line.